# What directory shell commands in Jenkins execute in?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, jenkins

I am looking at various Jenkins projects which have shell commands being executed as part of the build process. They are referencing and modifying variables that are not defined anywhere in the project.

I am trying to figure out what environment these shell scripts are being executed in. I read the [JenkinsWiki](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Administering+Jenkins) but it did not really explain what the PWD of the shell during processing of a particular Jenkins job. Googling [jenkins directory structure](https://www.google.com/search?q=jenkins%20directory&oq=jenkins%20directory&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.2351j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#q=jenkins%20directory%20structure) yields results which are mostly concerned with the internals of Jenkins itself, not the execution environment of my build jobs. **What directory shell commands in Jenkins execute in?**

Comment: This may be a dumb question, but what does 'pwd' yield when you're running a job? If I'm understanding your question correctly, that should give you the answer you're looking for. For instance, my jobs all run in `/var/lib/jenkins/job/<job_name>/workspace`.

Answer (score 0):

You can find the current working directory of a process using the proc subsystem:

```
# Get the PID using something like this:
PID=$( ps -o pid,cmd | grep jenkin[s] | awk '{print $1}' | head -n 1 )

# Use the proc subsystem
ls -l /proc/$PID/cwd
```